# Is date type more performant than datetime for queries on large datasets?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance, sqldatetime

I'm storing calendar event dates, including recurring events. The table could get huge. Most of my queries are for ranges of a month (i.e. where eventstart >= '1/1/2001' and eventstop <= '1/31/2001') so I don't care about time so much in my queries.

Would I get better performance in range queries if I queried a date column vs a datetime column?

Comment: I don't know but I'd say yes, as it is just 3 bytes compared to 8 bytes of `datetime`. Just for the record, you also have `smalldatetime`, which is 4 bytes, and that may be a fairer comparison.

Comment: Also, your queries would become more provably correct. In your example, `where eventstart >= '1/1/2001' and eventstop <= '1/31/2001'` with a `datetime` type you could miss an event on 31 January at 10am, say, because your range only goes up to midnight in the morning on 31 Jan. If it were a `date` column your query would always select any event in January. So if you don't need to store the time there are other advantages to the `date` type on top of speed and smaller storage requirements.

Comment: @Andrew, smalldatetime is not ANSI standard and it is recommended to not using it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx

Comment: An properly-defined index will help you a lot more than `datetime` or `date` will

Answer (score 1):

Rule 1)  Always use the smallest data size that will accommodate the largest possible value.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/datatypes/

Comment: Microsoft recommends to not using smalldatetime anymore. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx

Comment: Plus, the question was date or date time.  No one mentioned small date time except you.  But hey, thanks for the down vote.

Comment: Sorry, it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: I'll revert it if you accept my edit or you edit yourself.

Comment: Sir, Dont get me wrong. Site doesn't allow me to revert the dv, It says I can't revert until someone edit the answer. Please edit the answer and I'll revert it back.